# Failed to run post python script & 'Jupyter' is not reorganised internal or external command

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda3-5.0.1 32 bits on window 7.
When installation is about to complete it shows "Failed to run post python script  (PIC 1)".
After I clicked on ignore installation process is complete. Then in command it shows jupyter is not reorganized.
Please help.

[image]

[image]ps://i.stack.imgur.com/2EHZo.jpg

[image]

Comment: Your images are not included properly, you may want to edit your question

Answer (score 0):

just type in cmd "pip install jupyter"

after the installation type "jupyter notebook"
jupyter will run on browser.

if it doesn't work just type "python -m pip install jupyter"

Comment: Tried all this already n  there some issue in installing  anaconda